# C++ Random Number Generator in Array

Tags: c++, arrays

I'd like to write a program in C++, which will present 6 random numbers from 1 to 54. Below you could find the code. For some strange reason, when I run the program, I sometimes stumble upon an output like this:

> Bugunku sansli loto sayiniz:  17 1 12 32 33 3418568

I couldn't figure out why the last number ignores my rule.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Bugunku sansli loto sayiniz: " << endl;
    srand(time(0)); 
    int myArray [5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        myArray [i] = (rand() % 55) + 1;
        cout << myArray [i] << '\t';
    }
}
```

Comment: Out of bound access for `cout << myArray [i] << '\t';` with `i ==5`.

Comment: For six values you need an array that can hold six values: `int myArray [6];`

Comment: There are two hard things in computer science: cache invalidation, naming things, and off-by-one errors.

Comment: I'd advise to use the new <random> facilities if you are using C++11 or higher ... you can read up on it here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/

Comment: @Galik those are four things...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I couldn't figure out why the last number ignores my rule.

Because the last number accessed in the `for` loop is getting out of the bound of the array, dereference on it leads to UB. The `for` loop should be

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                    ~
```

Then `i` will be `0` ~ `4`, loop 5 times, not 6 times as your code shown.

You might use [range-based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) (since C++11) to avoid such kind of mistake:

```
for (auto& i : myArray) {
    i = (rand() % 55) + 1;
    cout << i << '\t';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> random numbers from 1 to 54

So this is incorrect as well: `(rand() % 55) + 1;`

You'll need `(rand() % 54) + 1;`

Answer (score 0):

Because you went to **myArray[5]** at the last time and your array don't have this place so you got it

you need to write like that:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Bugunku sansli loto sayiniz: " << endl;
    srand(time(0)); 
    int myArray [5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        myArray [i] = (rand() % 55) + 1;
        cout << myArray [i] << '\t';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want 6 items you need to make a array for six items

```
    int myArray[5];
```

this will provide 5 items where as

```
    int myArray[6];
```

this will provide you 6 items
This will fix your problem